# remove special escape python

Tags: python, string, escaping

I have the string

```
a = 'ddd\ttt\nnn'
```

I want to remove the '\' from the string. and It will be

```
a = 'dddtttnnn'
```

how to do that in python since '\t' and '\n' has special meaning in python

Comment: Just escape the `\ `, as in `\\ `.

Comment: Does your starting string actually contain `\t` and `\n` (tabs and new lines)?

Comment: `.replace("\t", "t").replace("\n", "n")`

Comment: @jason> Your question is unclear at the moment. You must edit it to make it explicit: does your string contain the literal characters (`d`, `d`, `d`, \, `t`, `t`, `t`, \, `n`, `n`, `n`) or tabs and new lines, that is, (`d`, `d`, `d`, `tab (\t)`, `t`, `t`, `newline (\n)`, `n`, `n`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggest.   my string is (d, d, d, \, t, t, t, \, n, n, n)

Comment: May I ask the question in another way?  What do you get if you `print` your string `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove `\t` and `\n` type characters (with those representing `tab` and `newline` in this case and remove the meaning of `\` in the string in general) you can do:

```
>>> a = 'ddd\ttt\nnn'
>>> print a
ddd tt
nn
>>> repr(a)[1:-1].replace('\\','')
'dddtttnnn'
>>> print repr(a)[1:-1].replace('\\','')
dddtttnnn
```

If it is a raw string (i.e., the `\` is not interpolated to a single character), you do not need the `repr`:

```
>>> a = r'ddd\ttt\nnn'
>>> a.replace('\\','')
'dddtttnnn'
```